# Java ThreadPool that allocates work by thread name

Tags: java, profiling, threadpool

I'm trying to build a ThreadPool that allocates work by thread name, the reason why I need to do this is because I'm doing some code profiling and in order to group the profiled data by some business key data, I'm using the thread name.

I managed to get something working but the threads are not as busy I would like them to be:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class NamedThreadPool {
    public HashMap<String, InThread> threads = new HashMap<String, InThread>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Random rnd = new Random();
        NamedThreadPool pool = new NamedThreadPool();
        final AtomicInteger executed = new AtomicInteger();
        final AtomicInteger active = new AtomicInteger();
        int count = 0;
        String[] years = { "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015" };
        while (true) {
            for (final String year : years) {
                count++;
                pool.queue(year, new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            active.incrementAndGet();
                            executed.incrementAndGet();
                            System.out.println("Executing [" + year + "], Active [" + format(active.get()) + "]");
                            Thread.sleep(rnd.nextInt(1000));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new NamedThreadPoolException("Error while running [" + year + "]", e);
                        } finally {
                            active.decrementAndGet();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            if (count == 20) {
                pool.shutdown();
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count + "<->" + executed.get());
    }

    public void queue(String name, Runnable runnable) {
        InThread thread = threads.get(name);
        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new InThread();
            thread.setName(name);
            threads.put(name, thread);
            thread.start();
        }
        thread.setRunnable(runnable);
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        for (InThread thread : threads.values()) {
            thread.blockIfActive();
            thread.disable();
        }
    }

    private class InThread extends Thread {
        private boolean enabled = true;
        private Runnable runnable;

        public synchronized void setRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
            blockIfActive();
            this.runnable = runnable;
            notifyAll();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            while (enabled) {
                try {
                    if (runnable != null) {
                        try {
                            runnable.run();
                        } finally {
                            runnable = null;
                            notifyAll();
                        }
                    } else {
                        wait();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new NamedThreadPoolException("Error while running [" + getName() + "]", e);
                }
            }
        }

        public synchronized void blockIfActive() {
            if (runnable != null) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new NamedThreadPoolException("Error while waiting [" + getName() + "]", e);
                }
            }
        }

        public synchronized void disable() {
            enabled = false;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public static String format(int num) {
        return new DecimalFormat("00000").format(num);
    }

    private static final class NamedThreadPoolException extends RuntimeException {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public NamedThreadPoolException(String message, Throwable cause) {
            super(message, cause);
        }

    }
}
```

If I profile that code using VisualVM I can see that many times the threads are in a waiting state for a long period, any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Johann

Comment: Err.. 'Thread.sleep(rnd.nextInt(1000));'.  What is that for?

Comment: It is to make the execution wait for some pseudo randomly time to try to emulate what would actually happen if I do run some code that needs some I/O